# Three.js 3D text

Tags: three.js

нужна помощь. Хочу сделать так чтобы 3D Текст менял размер свой, но никак не выходит. Если поможете буду благодарен Вот мой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
         <title>123123</title>
         <script src="./js/three.js"></script>
         <script src="./js/TrackballControls.js"></script>  
         <script src="./js/dat.gui.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script>

        
        init();
    
            function init()
            {
                

                var renderer = window.WebGLRenderingContext ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true}) : new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE));
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1,1000);

                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            
                var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
                var ambiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x141414);
        
                scene.add(ambiLight);
    
                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight();
                light.position.set(0, 80, 200);
                scene.add(light);
                


                var mytext = "3D text",
                size = 5,
                height = 3;
                                    
                var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
                fontLoader.load("./fonts/Academia Libera_Regular.json",function(font){
                var  text_Geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(mytext, {
                    size: size,
                    height: height,
                    
                    font: font});

                
                var Texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/1.jpg' ); 
                Texture.wrapS = Texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
                Texture.repeat.set( 0.05, 0.05 ); 
                var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: Texture } ); 
                
                var ExtrTexture =  THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/2.jpg' ); 
                ExtrTexture.wrapS = ExtrTexture.wrapT  = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                ExtrTexture.offset.set( 0, 0.7 );
                ExtrTexture.repeat.set( 0, 0.13 ); 
                var extrMaterial =  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: ExtrTexture } ); 
    
                var materials = [ Material, extrMaterial ]; 
                var text = new THREE.Mesh(text_Geometry, materials );
                text_Geometry.center();
                scene.add(text);

                var resize = new function() {
                        this.size = 5

                    }


                var gui = new dat.GUI();
                gui.add(resize,'size',5,30).listen()



                renderScene();

                function renderScene() 
                {



 
                requestAnimationFrame( renderScene );
                controls.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                }   


                })
                
             

                camera.position.x ==-50;
                camera.position.y = 70;
                camera.position.z = 200;
                camera.lookAt(scene.position);



            
            


                
            
};

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```